# Close excel whenever userform Closes

Tags: excel, vba

I created a password protected excel using VBA which only show limited/full access of sheets base on password input.

I made it work somehow, but the problem is if the user closes the form instead of inputting the password, they will be able to access the excel.

is there a that if the user closes the form using the "X" icon at the top right corner it will close the excel or workbook?

Thank you

Comment: In the code editor window for your form select your form in top left dropdown and in the top right hand side dropdown will be all the form events. See `Terminate` and `Unload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the form's `QueryClose` or `Terminate` event.

`QueryClose` gives you the option of canceling the closing based on your code.

[QueryClose event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/queryclose-event)

```
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.Quit
```

Here's an example of cancelling it:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
  If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to close Excel?", vbQuestion Or vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Quit
  Else
    Cancel = True
  End If
End Sub
```

<sub>Note: Keep in mind that there is no way to 100% prevent the user from "accessing the excel"</sub>